# How to get coordinates using useeffect?

Tags: reactjs

How to get coordinates using useeffect? I get nothing in return, what am I doing wrong?

```
const [position, setPosition] = useState<any>(null);
        
    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        const { longitude, latitude } = position.coords;
        console.log(longitude, latitude);
       });
      })();
    }, []);
```

Comment: Where is the await?...

Comment: I don't understand where to use it yet

Comment: If you used `async` you probably should use `await` with it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: could you answer why you wrap your function in an async IIFE?

Answer (score 0):

The geolocation API is native to supporting browsers. So you can remove `async` keyword.

```
 const [position, setPosition] = useState(null);
        
    useEffect(() => {
      (() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        //const { longitude, latitude } = position.coords;
        setPosition(position.coords)
       });
      })();
    }, []);
```

Then return `position` state. You can also `console.log()`